# Blender Bvh file export

Tags: animation, bvh

I am using Blender 3.31 to export a animation in bvh format file but the channels seem to be wrong.

[image]

Here the joint only has three channels rotation X,Y,Z but I want it to be 6, namely Position X Y Z together with Rotation

[image]

I set the location as the animation property and it is in the dope sheet animation channel

[image]

But when I export it into a bvh, the position channel are still missing, so how can I do to add the position channel?

Comment: Is the bone connected child of another bone? If so Loc channels are dismissed.

Comment: Yes it is connected child